# How to access namespace from Yii2 params.php

Tags: php, yii2, namespaces

I need to set some configurations values into an XML file. The configuration key is set well in `params.php` as an array. I wrote a simple class to load the xml entities and turn them into array.
I could not able to access this class from `params.php` in the config directory. It works fine from any controller like below:

```
use app\components\saidbakr\FoxXML;
...
public function actionIndex()
    {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r(FoxXML::loadXMLFile(__DIR__.'/../config/values/readers.xml')['reader']);
die();
...
```

However, in `params.php` I tried:

```
<?php
use app\components\saidbakr\FoxXml;
$siteName = Yii::t('app','Site Name');
return [
    'closeSite...
...
'readers' => FoxXML::loadXMLFile(__DIR__.'/../config/values/readers.xml')['reader'],
...
```

I got class not found:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'app\components\saidbakr\FoxXML' not found in /home/myuser/public/quran-yii2/config/params.php on line 62

Error: Class 'app\components\saidbakr\FoxXML' not found in /home/myuser/public/quran-yii2/config/params.php on line 62
```

I also tried to use the namespace in the entry script `web/index.php` `use app\components\saidbakr\FoxXML;` but I have the same issue.

How could I able to use a defined class methods in the configuration file?
I'm using PHP 7.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the app namespace is resolved by Yii's autoloader and it uses `@app` alias to resolve it. But alias is not yet set when parsing your params.php config. That's causing the class not found error.

Easy solution is to add the `app` namespace as PSR-4 namespace into your `composer.json` config:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "app\\": "."
    }
}
```

Then run `composer dump-autoload`.
Thanks to that the loading of class in `app` namespace will be handled by composer autoloader which is already set up when config files are parsed.

Comment: Great answer, but I have one question: Will this solution cause any performance issue because of double loading of that namespace? i.e here we loaded it manually using composer autoload and after a while Yii will load it again!

Comment: No, the class is not loaded twice. The autoloaders are called in order they were registered. If autoloader can load the class the class is loaded and the other autoloaders are not called for that class. If the autoloader cannot load class the next autoloader is called.